# Cannot parse string to date with tryparse exact

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I am reading a string from a log file with a date value like this:

```
 Thu Oct 06 15:38:45 2016
```

Obviously

```
 DateTime.TryParse()...
```

will not handle that. So, I tried using

```
 DateTime.TryParseExact()
```

like this:

```
        string szDateFormat = "ddd MMM yy HH:mm:ss yyyy";
        string szTest = "Thu Oct 06 15:38:45 2016";
        DateTime dd;
        DateTime.TryParse(szTest, out dd);

        CultureInfo current = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        CultureInfo newculture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        Console.WriteLine(current);
        Console.WriteLine(newculture);

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  Test: {0}", szTest));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Format: {0}", szDateFormat));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    dd: {0:ddd MMM yy HH:mm:ss yyyy}", dd));
        Console.WriteLine("");


        DateTime.TryParseExact(szTest, szDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dd);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("  Test: {0}", szTest));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Format: {0}", szDateFormat));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("    dd: {0:ddd MMM yy HH:mm:ss yyyy}", dd));
        Console.WriteLine("");
```

And the result is this:

```
    en-US
    en-US
      Test: Thu Oct 06 15:38:45 2016
    Format: ddd MMM yy HH:mm:ss yyyy
        dd: Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 0001

      Test: Thu Oct 06 15:38:45 2016
    Format: ddd MMM yy HH:mm:ss yyyy
        dd: Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 0001
```

In a previous iteration I used

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

as well with no change.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: You should be using "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy".

Comment: Are you reading the day of the month as a year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your date format is incorrect "ddd MMM **yy** HH:mm:ss yyyy" has to be

```
"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"
```

Comment: That is correct. I missed that. When I changed that to dd it worked perfectly using TryParseExact. Apparently my brain was frozen into thinking "day month year" and not "day month day". Thanks to all who pointed out my error. John

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to parse the numeric day (`06`) with `yy` when you should be using `dd`:

```
ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the problem:

```
string szDateFormat = "ddd MMM yy HH:mm:ss yyyy";
string szTest = "Thu Oct 06 15:38:45 2016";
```

the format should be:

```
ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy
```

if you want to parse:

```
Thursday 06.10.2016 15:38:45
```

The third parameter `yy`should be `dd` as it will conflict with the last parameter `yyyy`. `yy` is pointing to 2006, but the `yyyy` refers to 2016. This will create a confusion for the parser.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

1. "dd" is never set, since it is never parsed propery in the first place so " dd: Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 0001" is not really meaningful.
2. If your input format is always the same, pre-parse it for instance put the last 4 chars - year- in the start of the string)